# Estimating the maximum Grundy Number

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

What are some good methods to estimate the maximum possible Grundy Number that can occur while evaluating an impartial game, (assuming that the game has no subgames)?

*(This helps in estimating the size of data structures to use when calculating MEX)*.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure precisely what you are asking, but the [nimbers or Grundy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber) have the addition function 
$$\alpha \oplus \beta = \mathsf{mex}(\{\alpha^\prime \oplus \beta : \alpha^\prime \lt \alpha \} \cup \{\alpha \oplus \beta^\prime : \beta^\prime \lt \beta   \}$$ which is closed on the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,2^{k}-1\}$ for any integer $k$.

So you may want to use a bound of the next power of $2$ of the all the components of your impartial game.

In the unlikely event you also want to multiply nimbers, that is closed 
on the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,2^{2^n}-1\}$ for any integer $n$, so you have a bound which is the next number which is $2$ to the power of a power of $2$.

Comment: This is when I know the bounds on all subgames of in a super game. But I must calculate the Grundy numbers for all indivisible subgames. That grundy number maximum is what I am looking for. For example, for a single Nim tower, the max is the tower height itself!